# Passing data from view to view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to pass information from view to another view when pushing "Edytuj" button

[image: First view]

[image: Second view that needs presentationName from first view]

Here is my SlideController (secondView)

```
 public function slideindex()
{
    $list = Slide::all();


    return view('slide-list', ["slidesList" => $list, "title" => "Slides index"
        ]);
```

My routes

```
Route::get('index/createpresentation','DataController@createpresentation');

Route::post('index/','DataController@storepresentation');

Route::get('index/delete/{ID}','DataController@deletepresentation');

Route::get('index/edit/{ID}','SlideController@slideindex');

Route::get('index/','DataController@index');

Route::get('index/slideindex','SlideController@slideindex');
```

Blade of second view

```
@extends('template')

@section('title'){{@title}} @endsection

@section('content')

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/index">Index <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Dodaj slajd <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>

             <li class="nav-item active">
                <span class="navbar-brand ">Presentation Name</span>
            </li>


        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nazwa</th>
            <th>Typ</th>
            <th>Akcja</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($slidesList  as $slides )
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{$slides ->id}}</th>
                <td>{{$slides->slideName}}</td>
                <td>{{$slides->type}}</td>

            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@endsection('content')
```

<

It needs to be working same way when adding another records

Next i will need to assign same ID  to all new records in second view . In same ID i mean to send them ID that is corresponding to name that im trying to send

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of ways you can try

- Posting the data between forms with all the values you need
- Join the forms together and toggle between them using jquery/js
  functions
- Store the values in reddis or db of some sort so they can be re-used

Comment: Could you explain first solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass the ID of the row you want to edit?

You could create a route and a controller for this.

For example:

controller.php

```
public function show($id) 
{
// logic here
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'controller@show')->name('show.edit.form');
```

You could then create a link inside your forloop:

```
    @foreach ($slidesList  as $slides )
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{$slides ->id}}</th>
            <td>{{$slides->slideName}}</td>
            <td>{{$slides->type}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('show.edit.form', $slides->id) }}">EDIT</a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

If you want to show all slides corresponding to a presentation.
You could add a method inside your Presentation model:

```
public function slides()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Slide::class, 'your_foreign_key');
}
```

Then if you pass a presentation to a view, you could do something like this:

```
@foreach ($presentation->slides as $slide)
    // logic here
@endforeach
```

Comment: I need to pass name(nazwa prezentacji)  that ID is associated to, to the place that i pointed out , in second view

Comment: Im not quire sure what you are trying to achieve. Is the foreign key on the presentations the name?

Comment: In short the first view is for presentations , the second view is for slides that are in that presentation . So i need name that coresponds for that slides

Comment: Nah i was thinking i will put foreing key on ID so i can group results to only one ID

Comment: that 'name' needs to be here , <li class="nav-item active">
                <span class="navbar-brand ">Presentation Name</span>
            </li>